# Background image pattern with hoverable effect

Tags: html, css, svg, design-patterns, clip-path

Do you have any idea on how to make this kind of pattern?
I only have a background image like this and I want the 4 light-colored hexagons to be a link.

I already tried using svg but I think it will cost me more time on updating its responsiveness.

I also searched for other ways ( creating honeycomb patterns ) but I can't seem to find the best possible solution for this.

[image]

Comment: https://html.com/images/how-to-make-an-image-map/

Comment: easier if you don't use a background image but have the SVG inline since it can then be interactive.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think it will be time-consuming if I will make those patterns from scratch.

Comment: There are tools such as potrace that can convert raster images to SVG.

Comment: This is not possible with a *background image* as they are not elements and so not subject to selection by CSS or hover. A bg image is a *style*, not an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML image map, and define the areas of the hexagons as follows.

<sup>Note: I only put in the coordinates for the top right hexagon. The other ones would follow the same pattern.</sup>

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGR9G.jpg" width="1024" height="527" usemap="#map">

<map name="map">
  <area href="https://stackoverflow.com" shape="poly"
        coords="834,146, 888,146, 914,192, 888,236 834,236, 810,192">
</map>
```

Comment: May I ask how did you get the specific coords?

Comment: Just opened image in image editor, and looked them up. Those are the six corners of the hexagon.

Comment: Thanks. but it doesn't seem to work in a <section> with a background-image.

Comment: Need an img tag.

Comment: but I have a background image